# Oracle db: meta data case insentive

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Is oracle meta data(like table space name, table name etc..) is case insensitive ? I could not find it in  [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/toc.htm)  to confirm.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: This is documented in the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL": https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#i27561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is case sensitive, if you create a table with quotes round the name

eg. `CREATE TABLE "CamelCase"...`

it shows in `DBA_TABLES` as CamelCase

but without quotes

eg. `CREATE TABLE CamelCase...`

it shows in `DBA_TABLES` as CAMELCASE

Comment: Thanks.. that is test and prove way. is there oracle official document which explains this ?

Comment: sorry don't know of any document

Comment: @malatesh: the official document that explains this is called "the manual": https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements.htm#i193204